# How to get the identifier of stdClass Object as string?

Tags: php, object, web

I want to know how to get the "identifier" or the ID of the php object.
This is the `print_r` of the object.

```
Array ( [Qv4MO] => 
    stdClass Object ( 
        [ip] => 115.242.7.91 
        [campaign] => VQBU 
        [created_on] => 2013-02-17 01:50:51 
        ) 
    )
```

I want the "Qv4MO" as string !!

Please help me out...!

I can get the rest of the variables as `Object->ip or Object->campaign`
but how do I get the Object name.

Comment: Why are you using stdClass objects for data storage? They offer no real benefit over plain arrays, and have several drawbacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use function `key`

eg `echo key($array)`

Answer (score 0):

if $array is containing the above array then use `$array["Qv4MO"]->ip , $array["Qv4MO"]->campaign , $array["Qv4MO"]->created_on` and for object name use `key($array)`